# Java stream groupingby nested string

Tags: java

I have a list of string, and I want to be able to group them hierarchically.

Example of the list:

```
var list = new String[]{"caso.id",
"caso.unidadeDoCaso.id",
"caso.etiqueta",
"caso.sigiloso",
"caso.idPecaSegredoJustica",
"caso.numeroAno",
"caso.numero",
"caso.competencia.id",
"caso.competencia.ativo",
"caso.competencia.nome",
"caso.responsavel.id",
"caso.responsavel.dadosPessoais.nome",
"caso.escrivao.id",
"caso.escrivao.dadosPessoais.nome"};
```

I want to group them in Maps.
Like:

```
caso->
   id
   sigiloso,
   ...
   unidadeDoCaso->
              id
   competencia->
              id
              ativo
              ...
   responsavel->
             id
             dadosPessoais->
                       nome
                       ...
              ...
             
  ...
```

I was able to group just one level. I was wondering if there's a way to do it recursively.

Comment: Maps do not easily lend themselves to recursive definitions like `Map<String, Map<string, Map<string, ....>>>`  It would be something like `Map<String, Object>` and require casting to use.  I would recommend you use an alternative data structure such as a linked list to hold the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

In spite of my suggestion I decided to provide this. There are two recursive routines.

- one to fill the map.
- the other to print it.

```
String[] array = {
        "caso.id","caso.unidadeDoCaso.id","caso.etiqueta",
        "caso.sigiloso","caso.idPecaSegredoJustica","caso.numeroAno",
        "caso.numero","caso.competencia.id","caso.competencia.ativo",
        "caso.competencia.nome","caso.responsavel.id",
        "caso.responsavel.dadosPessoais.nome","caso.escrivao.id",
        "caso.escrivao.dadosPessoais.nome"
};
```

- Create the map
- Then iterated across the data, splitting on the dot.
- then call fill with the map, just split nodes, and the starting node index.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String s : array) {
    String[] nodes = s.split("\\.");
    fill(map, nodes, 0);
}

print(map, "");
```

prints

```
caso
   unidadeDoCaso
      id
   etiqueta
   idPecaSegredoJustica
   escrivao
      id
      dadosPessoais
         nome
   sigiloso
   numero
   id
   numeroAno
   responsavel
      id
      dadosPessoais
         nome
   competencia
      ativo
      nome
      id
```

The `fill` method continues until the supplied nodes are all processed.

- first the map is checked to see if the node exists or not(equal to null)
- if not present, a new map is constructed and added to the supplied map. Then the method is called to process the next node.
- otherwise, the method is called to add the current node to the map after the one that exists and continue processing the nodes.

```
public static void fill(Map<String, Object> map, String[] nodes, int i) {
    if (i >= nodes.length) {
        return;
    }
    String node = nodes[i];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>)(node);
    if (obj == null) {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(node, m);
        fill(m, nodes, i + 1);
    } else {
        fill( obj, nodes, i + 1);
    }
}
```

This prints the map elements and indents each subsequent nested map level on a separate line.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void print(Map<String, Object> map, String indent) {

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        if (key != null) {
            System.out.println(indent + key);
            print((Map<String, Object>) map.get(key), indent + "   ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Very simple and straight to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do this using a Map<String, Map> and [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) using the [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method that takes a supplier, accumulator, and combiner. The API is not the most pleasant to use, as WJS pointed out.

It requires unchecked casts because you can't represent these recursive structures of unknown depth using generics.

```
class Scratch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var list = new String[]{"caso.id",
            "caso.unidadeDoCaso.id",
            "caso.etiqueta",
            "caso.sigiloso",
            "caso.idPecaSegredoJustica",
            "caso.numeroAno",
            "caso.numero",
            "caso.competencia.id",
            "caso.competencia.ativo",
            "caso.competencia.nome",
            "caso.responsavel.id",
            "caso.responsavel.dadosPessoais.nome",
            "caso.escrivao.id",
            "caso.escrivao.dadosPessoais.nome"};

    Map<String, Map> result = Arrays.stream(list).collect(HashMap::new, Scratch::mapRecursively, HashMap::putAll);

    System.out.println(result);
    // {caso={unidadeDoCaso={id=null}, etiqueta=null, idPecaSegredoJustica=null, escrivao={id=null, dadosPessoais={nome=null}}, sigiloso=null, numero=null, id=null, numeroAno=null, responsavel={id=null, dadosPessoais={nome=null}}, competencia={ativo=null, nome=null, id=null}}}

    System.out.println(result.get("caso").keySet());
    // [unidadeDoCaso, etiqueta, idPecaSegredoJustica, escrivao, sigiloso, numero, id, numeroAno, responsavel, competencia]
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void mapRecursively(HashMap<String, Map> map, String s) {
    // first recursion: s = caso.competencia.id
    // second recursion: s = id

    int dot = s.indexOf('.');

    // Base case 1
    if (dot == -1) {
        map.put(s, null);
        return;
    }

    String key = s.substring(0, dot); // caso
    String value = s.substring(dot + 1); // competencia.id

    boolean isFirstTimeToComeAcrossWord = !map.containsKey(key);
    if (isFirstTimeToComeAcrossWord) {
        map.put(key, new HashMap<>());
    }

    // Base case 2
    int dot2 = value.indexOf('.');

    if (dot2 == -1) {
        map.get(key).put(value, null);
        return;
    }

    String newKey = value.substring(0, dot2); // competencia
    String leftover = value.substring(dot2 + 1); // id

    boolean isFirstTimeWeComeAcrossNestedWord = !map.get(key).containsKey(newKey);
    // Recursive cases
    if (isFirstTimeWeComeAcrossNestedWord) {
        var newMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();
        map.get(key).put(newKey, newMap);
        mapRecursively(newMap, leftover);
    } else {
        mapRecursively((HashMap<String, Map>) map.get(key).get(newKey), leftover);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect. You have such a privileged mind.